# Why do I get a Cannot read from a closed TextReader, when using it in windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have the following code in my Windows phone application, that crashes with the exception: Cannot read from a closed TextReader.

Can someone tell me why, I cant figure out whats wrong.

```
    IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

                IsolatedStorageFileStream FS = ISF.OpenFile("ipview.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(FS))
                {



                        while (!SR.EndOfStream)
                        {
                             Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                           IPHistoryBox.Items.Add(SR.ReadLine());
                    });
                        }



                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is executed on the dispatcher thread after the `StreamReader` is closed:

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
 {
     IPHistoryBox.Items.Add(SR.ReadLine());
 });
```

change it like this:

```
 var x = SR.ReadLine();
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>IPHistoryBox.Items.Add(x));
```

This way the `StreamReader` is read on the current thread and the result is used on the Dispatcher thread.